# Multiply every element of matrix with a vector to obtain a matrix whose elements are vectors themselves

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I need help in speeding up the following block of code:

```
import numpy as np
    x = 100
    pp = np.zeros((x, x)) 
    M = np.ones((x,x))
    arrayA = np.random.uniform(0,5,2000)
    arrayB = np.random.uniform(0,5,2000)
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(x):
            y = np.multiply(arrayA, np.exp(-1j*(M[j,i])*arrayB))
            p = np.trapz(y, arrayB)  # Numerical evaluation/integration y
            pp[j,i] = abs(p**2)
```

Is there a function in numpy or another method to rewrite this piece of code with so that the nested for-loops can be omitted? My idea would be a function that multiplies every element of M with the vector arrayB so we get a 100 x 100 matrix in which each element is a vector itself. And then further each vector gets multiplied by arrayA with the np.multiply() function to then again obtain a 100 x 100 matrix in which each element is a vector itself. Then at the end perform numerical integration for each of those vectors with np.trapz() to obtain a 100 x 100 matrix of which each element is a scalar.

My problem though is that I lack knowledge of such functions which would perform this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:**
Using broadcasting with

```
 M = np.asarray(M)[..., None]
         y = 1000*arrayA*np.exp(-1j*M*arrayB)
         return np.trapz(y,B)
```

works and I can ommit the for-loops. However, this is not faster, but instead a little bit slower in my case. This might be a memory issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want `M = np.ones((x,x))` ?  Because that makes things sort of trivial. (all of `pp` end up the same value)

Comment: Also, should `arrayB` be sorted?  I can't imagine the purpose if it's not.

Comment: M is just a placeholder matrix, as is arrayA and arrayB.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = np.multiply(arrayA, np.exp(-1j*(M[j,i])*arrayB))
```

can be written as

```
y = arrayA * np.exp(-1j*M[:,:,None]*arrayB
```

producing a (x,x,2000) array.

But the next step may need adjustment.  I'm not familiar with `np.trapz`.

```
np.trapz(y, arrayB)
```